# angular - primeng - confirmdialog not working

Tags: angular, primeng, angular7

Angular 7 - primeng - confirmdialog not working

HTML

```
<p>confirm-dialog</p>
<button type="button" (click)="confirm()" pButton icon="pi pi-check" label="Confirm"></button>
```

Typescript

```
  confirm() {
console.log('confirm called...')
this.confirmationService.confirm({
  message: 'Are you sure that you want to proceed?',
  header: 'Confirmation',
  icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
  accept: () => {
    this.msgs = [{ severity: 'info', summary: 'Confirmed', detail: 'You have accepted' }];
    console.log('accept...')
  },
  reject: () => {
    this.msgs = [{ severity: 'info', summary: 'Rejected', detail: 'You have rejected' }];
  }
});
```

Full Code here on Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/jjay-angular-primeng-gaiizg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: <p-confirmDialog></p-confirmDialog>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `<p>confirm-dialog</p>` you have to use something `<p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" width="425"></p-confirmDialog>`

Comment: Thanks mate, I missed it.